# Skip first few items in ul

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Trying to set a divider but I want to skip the first few items in my `ul`. Cannot get it to work.

```html
<ul>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS with tailwind

```css
ul {
   @apply divide-y;
}
```

I cannot skip the first three items. For those three items I do NOT want the divider. How to make?

Tried a dozen variations with this code:

css

```
ul > li:not(:nth-child(-n + 3)) {
  @apply divide-y;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Boq7, did you try https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `divide-y` class should always be associated with the parent element. The purpose of the class is to place a **`border`** between child elements that appears **as a visual `divider`**.

**If you don't want to see the divider on the first 3 elements, simply disable the border.**

```css
ul {
  @apply divide-y;
}
ul > li:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  @apply border-none;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  ul {
    @apply divide-y;
  }
  ul > li:nth-child(-n + 3) {
    @apply border-none;
  }
</style>

<ul>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>NO divider here</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
   <li>YES divider</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that with `divide-none` which did not work, but did not think about `border-none`. That worked perfectly, thanks a lot.